# apache2 not serving css file despite showing file in directory

Tags: html, css, apache, web, jekyll

I have a website I am trying to host, but for whatever reason, apache2 is refusing to serve the css file I have for my website. I have not change any settings and everything is completely default. I installed apache in the past 2 weeks so everything is clean and fresh.

All I did was copy all the files generated by jekyll from the `_site` folder and put them into `/var/www/html` on my server. now, when I go to my website, I can see all the content and the html loads correctly. The links work, images work. but there is no css styling available.

Because the default settings on apache arent that good, i can browse the folder contents. for example, my css file is store in `/var/www/html/assets/css/style.css`. So, when I access the website by going to `https://mywebsite.com/assets/css`, I can see the file structure and apache shows that I have a css file in there. but, when I try and click on that file, I get a

```
Not Found.
The requested URL was not found on this server. 
----
Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at xxxx.com Port 443
```

All other files can be browsed in the folder structure and every file appears to be present, its just the pesky css file that will not load.

Comment: How did u added the css file to html? Maybe u made a mistake linking it. If not try to link from root to css file and not from the html file.

Comment: Is there any helpful information in Apache's `error_log`?  Sometimes it will say where it is looking for the file.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers should be asked on [sf]. Please clarify your question by including information from the error log before posting it there.